# Microphone works in Zoom but not in Browsers

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, microphone

I use a Lenovo Ideapad 330 and I have an issue where my Realtek microphone works in Zoom Meetings and Windows Sound Recorder but not in either Chrome or Firefox. Although in Firefox it produces a distorted echo-like sound and I can barely hear myself. Web apps such as Google Meet on Chrome say that my mic is Ok although while testing it I completely do not hear anything. I downgraded from Windows 10 to 8.1 for quite obvious reasons and I am not really sure if my mic worked on Windows 10. My webcam works in most cases apart from the Windows 8.1 built-in metro camera app. Can someone help me please as the microphone is essential to my studies.

**Edit:** I have tried disabling extensions in Chrome and has not worked. I do not have extensions in Firefox.

Comment: Which obvious reasons caused you to downgrade from a good OS to an insecure one?

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10 is good?

Comment: It's far beyond Windows 8.1.